# Tuning an write-only master mysql database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I have an master database when I only run write queries (inserts, deletes, updates).
I would like to know how to tune this having in mind that selects are not important here.
I'm using InnoDB. Replication with 1 Master and 2 Slaves. Running on a Ubuntu 16.04 server. MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Disable the [query cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html). It's only beneficial for reads.
- Disable the [adaptive hash index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-adaptive-hash.html). It's only beneficial for reads.
- Increase the [innodb_log_file_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size). I recommend at least 2GB, unless disk space is short.
- Drop indexes, except for those used by your `UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements. You can create more indexes on the slave to support `SELECT` queries.
- Consider [fine-tuning the Buffer Pool Flushing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-lru-background-flushing.html). The optimal settings depend on your workload, so you'll have to experiment.
- If you want to sacrifice durability, you can make some other changes. Warning: these increase the risk of data loss.

  - [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) = 2 or 0 to relax synchronous log writes.
  - [innodb_doublewrite](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_doublewrite) = OFF to disable page write protections.
  - [sync_binlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_sync_binlog) = 0 to disable synchronous writes to the binary log.
- Make sure your data directory is on fast disks, like SSD or a caching RAID array.
- Never use NFS.
- You may experiment with putting [innodb_log_group_home_dir](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_group_home_dir) and [innodb_undo_directory](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-undo-tablespace.html) and [log_bin_basename](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_basename) and [tmpdir](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir) on different physical volumes from your data directory. But this won't give a benefit unless performance is really disk-bound.

Further tuning depends on your workload. For example, changing the thread concurrency or the number of IO write threads or the IO capacity. If you want to go to this level of tuning, get some consulting from a professional.

---

Comment from @spencer7593 brings up a good point, you might not be able to achieve the best optimization solely with database tuning options.

You haven't mentioned anything about the application or the type of writes, but eventually you'll have to consider changing the way you write to the database. Tuning changes alone are limited in how they improve database performance.

For example, applications could write to a queue, then create a consumer app to consume items from the queue and write data to the database in larger batches. That means more efficient database writes, but more importantly it allows applications to "write" with much lower latency because they are only writing to a queue.

Eventually, you may find that no single database instance can keep up with the rate of writes. At that point, you'll have to scale out, by spreading writes over multiple database instances. This is called "sharding" the data. Of course this adds more complexity to database reads, because your data is not all together. So try all the tuning changes you can try before resorting to sharding.

Comment: I think we should also note that processing RBAR (row by agonizing row)... e.g. a tight loop performing a bloatload of singleton INSERT statements is a sure way to drag down performance. No amount of server tuning is going to address tuning the workload, the transactions that are being executed. +10

Comment: @spencer7593, true, but I have no idea about the OP's application design. Could be a lot of individual events being inserted into the database one at a time. Typical data-collection-from-many-instruments workload, which is getting more common with the advent of IoT.